# Computing ROC curves without scores

Tags: r, statistics, prediction, roc, auc

I am working with a gene priorization program and I want to analyze its performance by making use of ROC curves and the ROCR package for R. The problem is that the program does not give me a score for each gene, it only orders the genes.

ROCR only uses continuous data as predictions. Is it possible to assign to each gene a number in descending order? For example, I have these genes ordered:

- Gene A
- Gene B
- Gene C

I could assign these values?

- Gene A: 3
- Gene B: 2
- Gene C: 1

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify what your program does? How does it order genes?

Comment: It assigns a score for each gene and orders them but it doesn't show the scores.  For this reason, I considered to use arbitrary scores in descending order.

Comment: ROC analysis doesn't depend on the absolute values so you are good with the order only. But I fail to see the binary classification aspect. What are you trying to predict with the scores?

Comment: What I want is to order the genes, those related with the disease will be the most probable disease casual genes. Seed genes are represented as 1 and non-seed as 0. The vallidation considers seed genes as causal genes although it's an approximation.